# Laravel @section Does not seem to be working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I have a Blade named `dashboard.blade.php` which goes like this:

```
@extends( 'frontend.dashboard_main' )

@section('title')  Profile  @endsection
@section('style')
   SOME CUSTOM STYLES
@endsection
```

And `dashboard.blade.php` goes like this:

```
@include( 'frontend.header' )
...
```

And at `header.blade.php`, I added these:

```
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
@yield('style')
...
```

But now the problem is, **SOME CUSTOM STYLES** does not seem to be working and `@yield('style')` not loads css styles.

So if you know what's going wrong here, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

For including  `css` and `js` files in extended view .Better use stack instead of yield

Inside `frontend/dashboard_main`

```
 <header>
other css files and meta
@stack('styles')
</header>
```

and in extended view

```
@push('styles')
   <style>

</style>
@endpush
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks